# Please help with the diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: Please help me to draw the digram mentioned in the above image uploaded.]

Please help me to draw the digram mentioned in the above image uploaded.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: As as starting point: I usally use TikZ nodes for this (e.g `\node [rectangle,draw,minimum width=...,minimum height=...,outer padding=0pt] (X1) at (x,y) {}` [not 100% sure about the option names now]). Then you can use the node names to draw the lines. Give it a try and when you are getting stuck to hard post your code here and ask for specific points.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\tikzset{BoxNode/.style={draw,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=0.6cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[BoxNode] (x1) at (0,0){};
\node[BoxNode,below=0cm of x1.south] (x2){};
\node[BoxNode,below=3cm of x2] (xn){};
\draw[ultra thick,loosely dotted](x2.south)--(xn.north);
\foreach \i in {1,2,n}
{\draw[latex-] (x\i.west)--++(-1cm,0) node[midway,above] {$x_\i$};}
\node[BoxNode,label=above:$f_1$] (z1) at (4,1){};
\node[BoxNode,below=0cm of z1.south] (z2){};
\node[BoxNode,below=0cm of z2.south] (z3){};
\node[BoxNode,below=0cm of z3.south] (z4){};
\node[BoxNode,below=3cm of z4] (zm){};
\draw[ultra thick,loosely dotted](z4.south)--(zm.north);
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,m}
{\draw[latex-] (z\i.east)--++(1cm,0) node[midway,above] {$z_\i$};}
\node[BoxNode,label=above:$f_1$] (y1) at (8,0){};
\node[BoxNode,below=0cm of y1.south] (y2){};
\node[BoxNode,below=3cm of y2] (yR){};
\draw[ultra thick,loosely dotted](y2.south)--(yR.north);
\foreach \i in {1,2,R}
{\draw[-latex] (y\i.east)--++(1cm,0) node[midway,above] {$y_\i$};}
\foreach \i in {1,2,n}
{\draw[-,thin,gray] (x\i.east)--(z1.west) node[pos=0.4,above,sloped] {$w_{\i1}$};}
\foreach \i in {1,2,m}
{\draw[-,thin,gray] (z\i.east)--(y1.west) node[pos=0.4,above,sloped] {$v_{\i1}$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]